# how to select unique records from a table based on a column which has distinct values in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table SUBJ_SKILLS which has records like

```
TCHR_ID | LINE_NBR | SUBJ             | SUBJ_TYPE     
--------| -------  | ----------       | ---------- 
1       | 1        | Maths            | R
1       | 2        | 101              | U
2       | 1        | BehaviourialTech | U
3       | 2        | Maths            | R
4       | 1        | RegionalLANG     | U
5       | 3        | ForeignLANG      | U
5       | 4        | Maths            | R
6       | 2        | Science          | R
7       | 1        | 101              | U
7       | 3        | Physics          | R
..
..
```

I am trying to retrieve records like below (i.e. single teacher who taught multiple different subjects)

```
TCHR_ID | LINE_NBR | SUBJ        | SUBJ_TYPE
--------| -------  | ----------  | ----------
5       | 3        | ForeignLANG | U
5       | 4        | Maths       | R
7       | 1        | 101         | U
7       | 3        | Physics     | R
1       | 1        | Maths       | R    
1       | 2        | 101         | U
```

Here, the line numbers are unique, means that TCHR_ID:5 taught Physics (which was LINE_NBR=1, but was removed later). So, the LINE_NBR are not updated and stay as is.

i also have a look up table (SUBJ_LKUP) for subject and their categories/type like below ('R' for Regular subject and 'U' for Unique subject )

```
   SUBJ              | SUBJ_TYPE
  -----------------  | ------------
   Maths             | R
   Physics           | R
   ForeignLANG       | U
   101               | U
   Science           | R
   BehaviourialTech  | U
   RegionalLANG      | U
```

My approach to resolve this was to create a table which have 2 records for Teacher and use another query on base table (SUBJ_SKILLS) and new table to filter out distinct records. I came up with below queries..

Query-1:

```
create table tchr_with_2_subj as select SS.TCHR_ID 
from SUBJ_SKILLS SS, SUBJ_LKUP SL 
where SS.SUBJ = SL.SUBJ
and SL.SUBJ_TYPE IN ('R', 'U') AND SS.TCHR_ID IN
    (select SS.TCHR_ID from SUBJ_SKILLS SS)
     GROUP BY SS.TCHR_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Query-2:

```
select SS.TCHR_ID from SUBJ_SKILLS SS, tchr_with_2_subj tw2s
where  SS.TCHR_ID = tw2s.TCHR_ID
GROUP BY SS.TCHR_ID,SS.SUBJ_TYPE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Question:

1)'IN' condition in Query-1 is causing problems and pulling wrong records.

2) Is there a better way to write query to pull matching records using a single query (i.e. instead of creating a table)

Could someone help me on this pls.

Comment: not sure, why do you need to join `SUBJ_SKILLS` and `SUBJ_LKUP`. Is there a specific reason, which is not mentioned in the question ?

Comment: there might be chances where i might have SUBJ as NULL or junk data

Answer (score 0):

For the answer to your original question, I would use window functions:

```
select ss.*
from (select ss.*,
             min(subj) over (partition by tchr_id) as mins,
             max(subj) over (partition by tchr_id) as maxs
      from SUBJ_SKILLS ss
     ) ss
where mins <> maxs;
```

It is unclear how the subject type fits in, but if you need to include that, similar logic will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your second table can be obtained from your first table with:

```
select ss.*
from
    subj_skills as ss
    inner join (
        select tchr_id
        from subj_skills
        group by tchr_id
        having count(*) > 1
        ) as mult on mult.tchr_id=ss.tchr_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use analytic functions here, asomething like:

```
select tchr_id, line_nbr, subj, SUBJ_TYPE
from (select count(distinct subj) over (partition by tchr_id) as grp_cnt,
             s.*
      from subj_skills s)
where grp_cnt > 1
```

If you need to filter out invalid records, you can do it in the inner query. If a teacher cannot teach the same subject multiple times (the req 'multiple different subjects' can be translated to 'multiple subjects'), then I'd rather use count(*) instead of count(distinct subj).